# Same-origin policy preventing me from getting selected text inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am trying to read user-selected text inside an iframe from a different origin or domain.

Actual use-case:

1. There is an iframe on my page with content from another domain
2. The user highlights some text inside the iframe
3. The user then clicks a button on the side (outside of the iframe)
4. The text is then saved and highlighted within the iframe

I took a look at this page about [circumventing same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy), but I am not sure which method would be suitable since I am particularly inexperienced in this area. I am looking for a little guidance, thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you are unable to access to the content of an iframe from a different domain

Comment: It can't be done, for security reasons. Unless you have control of the domain inside the iframe.

Comment: I suppose I'll have to create a proxy on my server then, any idea the best way to do that?

Comment: @ibopm Do you control the URL of the IFRAME?

Comment: @David-SkyMesh nope, I need to get the selected text inside the iframe.

Comment: @ibopm If you don't control the URL, it will be much harder to implement the proxy. There could be all sorts of content inside the IFRAME which will have HTTP links/includes that are difficult to identify and rewrite.